# capping BigInteger numbers

Tags: java, biginteger

My code is meant to find the largest product of 13 adjacent numbers in the very large number but for some reason it is capping the BigInteger "product" at 6429780.

```
public class Euler8 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String number=//large 1000 digit number
        BigInteger[] anarray=new BigInteger[13];
        BigInteger product=new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger maxproduct=new BigInteger("0");
        int y=0;

        for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++){
            anarray[y]=BigInteger.valueOf(Long.valueOf(Character.toString(number.charAt(i))));
            y++;
            if(i>=12){
                for(BigInteger x : anarray) {
                    if(x.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0||x.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==1) {
                    product = product.multiply(x);
                    }
                }
                if(product.compareTo(maxproduct)==1){
                    maxproduct=product;`

                }
                y=0;
                product=BigInteger.ONE;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maxproduct);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You reset y to 0 after every iteration of the loop, so you only ever replace the first element of the array after adding the first 13 numbers.

Comment: Thanks cant believe I didn't catch that